# In Laravel, the best way to pass different types of flash messages in the session

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4

I'm making my first app in Laravel and am trying to get my head around the session flash messages. As far as I'm aware in my controller action I can set a flash message either by going

```
Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', 'Thanks for registering!'); //is this actually OK?
```

For the case of redirecting to another route, or

```
Session::flash('message', 'This is a message!');
```

In my master blade template I'd then have:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<p class="alert alert-info">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif
```

As you may have noticed I'm using Bootstrap 3 in my app and would like to make use of the different message classes: `alert-info`, `alert-warning`, `alert-danger` etc.

Assuming that in my controller I know what type of message I'm setting, what's the best way to pass and display it in the view? Should I set a separate message in the session for each type (e.g. `Session::flash('message_danger', 'This is a nasty message! Something's wrong.');`)? Then I'd need a separate if statement for each message in my blade template.

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-5-implement-flash-messages-with-exampleexample.html was helpful for me.

Answer (score 275, accepted):

One solution would be to flash two variables into the session:

1. The message itself
2. The "class" of your alert

for example:

```
Session::flash('message', 'This is a message!'); 
Session::flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');
```

Then in your view:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
<p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>
@endif
```

Note I've put a [default value](http://laravel.com/docs/session#session-usage) into the `Session::get()`.  that way you only need to override it if the warning should be something other than the `alert-info` class.

*(that is a quick example, and untested :) )*

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about the default parameter for `Session::get()`  That will come in super handy.

Comment: Like most flash message solutions, this only deals with one message. So often, it is necessary to be able to fire off a bunch of messages, each maybe a different severity, and have them all displayed.

Comment: Here's what we are using in our projects https://gist.github.com/YavorK/7aa6e839dbe93e8854e4b033e31836a4

Comment: This is so counter productive... Why is everyone upvoting this?

Comment: @Goowik - Saying its counter productive while not offering a more productive solution is counter productive.

Comment: @SupaMonkey Duplication of solutions is counter productive.

Answer (score 60):

In your view:

```
<div class="flash-message">
  @foreach (['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'] as $msg)
    @if(Session::has('alert-' . $msg))
    <p class="alert alert-{{ $msg }}">{{ Session::get('alert-' . $msg) }}</p>
    @endif
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Then set a flash message in the controller:

```
Session::flash('alert-danger', 'danger');
Session::flash('alert-warning', 'warning');
Session::flash('alert-success', 'success');
Session::flash('alert-info', 'info');
```

Answer (score 51):

My way is to always Redirect::back() or Redirect::to():

```
Redirect::back()->with('message', 'error|There was an error...');

Redirect::back()->with('message', 'message|Record updated.');

Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'success|Record updated.');
```

I have a helper function to make it work for me, usually this is in a separate service:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

function displayAlert()
{
      if (Session::has('message'))
      {
         list($type, $message) = explode('|', Session::get('message'));

         $type = $type == 'error' ?: 'danger';
         $type = $type == 'message' ?: 'info';

         return sprintf('<div class="alert alert-%s">%s</div>', $type, $message);
      }

      return '';
}
```

And in my view or layout I just do

```
{{ displayAlert() }}
```

Comment: This is simply awesome but how does this work `$type = $type == 'error' : 'danger';`

Comment: Where do you put your helper in a seperate Helper Class?

Comment: It should be `{!! displayAlert() !!}`

Answer (score 25):

You can make a multiple messages and with different types.
Follow these steps below:

1. Create a file: "`app/Components/FlashMessages.php`"

> ```
> namespace App\Components;
>
> trait FlashMessages
> {
>   protected static function message($level = 'info', $message = null)
>   {
>       if (session()->has('messages')) {
>           $messages = session()->pull('messages');
>       }
>
>       $messages[] = $message = ['level' => $level, 'message' => $message];
>
>       session()->flash('messages', $messages);
>
>       return $message;
>   }
>
>   protected static function messages()
>   {
>       return self::hasMessages() ? session()->pull('messages') : [];
>   }
>
>   protected static function hasMessages()
>   {
>       return session()->has('messages');
>   }
>
>   protected static function success($message)
>   {
>       return self::message('success', $message);
>   }
>
>   protected static function info($message)
>   {
>       return self::message('info', $message);
>   }
>
>   protected static function warning($message)
>   {
>       return self::message('warning', $message);
>   }
>
>   protected static function danger($message)
>   {
>       return self::message('danger', $message);
>   }
> }
> ```

2. On your base controller "`app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php`".

> ```
> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
> use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
> use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
> use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
> use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;
>
> use App\Components\FlashMessages;
>
> class Controller extends BaseController
> {
>     use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;
>
>     use FlashMessages;
> }
> ```

This will make the `FlashMessages` trait available to all controllers that extending this class.

3. Create a blade template for our messages: "`views/partials/messages.blade.php`"

> ```
> @if (count($messages))
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-md-12">
>   @foreach ($messages as $message)
>       <div class="alert alert-{{ $message['level'] }}">{!! $message['message'] !!}</div>
>   @endforeach
>   </div>
> </div>
> @endif
> ```

4. On "`boot()`" method of "`app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`":

> ```
> namespace App\Providers;
>
> use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider; 
>
> use App\Components\FlashMessages;
>
> class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
> {
>   use FlashMessages;
>
>     public function boot()
>     {
>         view()->composer('partials.messages', function ($view) {
>
>           $messages = self::messages();
>
>           return $view->with('messages', $messages);
>       });
>     }
>
>     ...
> }
> ```

This will make the `$messages` variable available to "`views/partials/message.blade.php`" template whenever it is called.

5. On your template, include our messages template - "`views/partials/messages.blade.php`"

> ```
> <div class="row">
>   <p>Page title goes here</p>
> </div>
>
> @include ('partials.messages')
>
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="col-md-12">
>       Page content goes here
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

You only need to include the messages template wherever you want to display the messages on your page.

6. On your controller, you can simply do this to push flash messages:

> ```
> use App\Components\FlashMessages;
>
> class ProductsController {
>
>   use FlashMessages;
>
>   public function store(Request $request)
>   {
>       self::message('info', 'Just a plain message.');
>       self::message('success', 'Item has been added.');
>       self::message('warning', 'Service is currently under maintenance.');
>       self::message('danger', 'An unknown error occured.');
>
>       //or
>
>       self::info('Just a plain message.');
>       self::success('Item has been added.');
>       self::warning('Service is currently under maintenance.');
>       self::danger('An unknown error occured.');
>   }
>
>   ...
> ```

Hope it'l help you.

Comment: Nice. Actually need to find solution for multiple messages in Laravel.

Answer (score 18):

Simply return with the 'flag' that you want to be treated without using any additional user function.
The Controller:

```
return \Redirect::back()->withSuccess( 'Message you want show in View' );
```

Notice that I used the 'Success' flag.

The View:

```
@if( Session::has( 'success' ))
     {{ Session::get( 'success' ) }}
@elseif( Session::has( 'warning' ))
     {{ Session::get( 'warning' ) }} <!-- here to 'withWarning()' -->
@endif
```

Yes, it really works!

Comment: You have a ton of typos in your answer, but your approach works great.

Answer (score 7):

Another solution would be to create a helper class
[How to Create helper classes here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088917/what-are-the-best-practices-and-best-places-for-laravel-4-helpers-or-basic-funct)

```
class Helper{
     public static function format_message($message,$type)
    {
         return '<p class="alert alert-'.$type.'">'.$message.'</p>'
    }
}
```

Then you can do this.

```
Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', Helper::format_message('A bla blah occured','error'));
```

or

```
Redirect::to('users/login')->with('message', Helper::format_message('Thanks for registering!','info'));
```

and in your view

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    {{Session::get('message')}}
@endif
```

Comment: I don't know if I would recommend this approach since it's taking HTML out of the view and into code.

Answer (score 5):

Not a big fan of the solutions provided (ie: multiple variables, helper classes, looping through 'possibly existing variables'). Below is a solution that instead uses an array as opposed to two separate variables. It's also easily extendable to handle multiple errors should you wish but for simplicity, I've kept it to one flash message:

Redirect with flash message **array**:

```
    return redirect('/admin/permissions')->with('flash_message', ['success','Updated Successfully','Permission "'. $permission->name .'" updated successfully!']);
```

Output based on array content:

```
@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            bootstrapNotify('{{session('flash_message')[0]}}','{{session('flash_message')[1]}}','{{session('flash_message')[2]}}');
        });
    </script>
@endif
```

Unrelated since you might have your own notification method/plugin - but just for clarity - bootstrapNotify is just to initiate bootstrap-notify from http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/:

```
function bootstrapNotify(type,title = 'Notification',message) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'success':
            icon = "la-check-circle";
            break;
        case 'danger':
            icon = "la-times-circle";
            break;
        case 'warning':
            icon = "la-exclamation-circle";
    }

    $.notify({message: message, title : title, icon : "icon la "+ icon}, {type: type,allow_dismiss: true,newest_on_top: false,mouse_over: true,showProgressbar: false,spacing: 10,timer: 4000,placement: {from: "top",align: "right"},offset: {x: 30,y: 30},delay: 1000,z_index: 10000,animate: {enter: "animated bounce",exit: "animated fadeOut"}});
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just send an array in the session rather than a string, like this:

```
Session::flash('message', ['text'=>'this is a danger message','type'=>'danger']);

@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{session('message')['type']}}">
        {{session('message')['text']}}
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use Laravel Macros.

You can create `macros.php`  in `app/helpers` and include it routes.php.

if you wish to put your macros in a class file instead, you can look at this tutorial: http://chrishayes.ca/blog/code/laravel-4-object-oriented-form-html-macros-classes-service-provider

```
HTML::macro('alert', function($class='alert-danger', $value="",$show=false)
{

    $display = $show ? 'display:block' : 'display:none';

    return
        '<div class="alert '.$class.'" style="'.$display.'">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <strong><i class="fa fa-times"></i></strong>'.$value.'
        </div>';
});
```

In your controller:

```
Session::flash('message', 'This is so dangerous!'); 
Session::flash('alert', 'alert-danger');
```

In your View

```
@if(Session::has('message') && Session::has('alert') )
  {{HTML::alert($class=Session::get('alert'), $value=Session::get('message'), $show=true)}}
@endif
```

Answer (score 4):

For my application i made a helper function:

```
function message( $message , $status = 'success', $redirectPath = null )
{
     $redirectPath = $redirectPath == null ? back() : redirect( $redirectPath );

     return $redirectPath->with([
         'message'   =>  $message,
         'status'    =>  $status,
    ]);
}
```

message layout, `main.layouts.message`:

```
@if($status)
   <div class="center-block affix alert alert-{{$status}}">
     <i class="fa fa-{{ $status == 'success' ? 'check' : $status}}"></i>
     <span>
        {{ $message }}
     </span>
   </div>
@endif
```

and import every where to show message:

```
@include('main.layouts.message', [
    'status'    =>  session('status'),
    'message'   =>  session('message'),
])
```

Answer (score 4):

In Controller:

```
Redirect::to('/path')->with('message', 'your message');
```

Or

```
Session::flash('message', 'your message');
```

in Blade show message in Blade As ur Desired Pattern:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-className">
        {{session('message')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: How you pass the className ?

Comment: Simple and works in Laravel 10

Comment: This is no different from what OP already has, except `alert-className` is not a valid alert class.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do this

in my store() function i put success alert once it saved properly.

```
\Session::flash('flash_message','Office successfully updated.');
```

in my destroy() function, I wanted to color the alert red so to notify that its deleted

```
\Session::flash('flash_message_delete','Office successfully deleted.');
```

Notice, we create two alerts with different flash names.

And in my view, I will add condtion to when the right time the specific alert will be called

```
@if(Session::has('flash_message'))
    <div class="alert alert-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><em> {!! session('flash_message') !!}</em></div>
@endif
@if(Session::has('flash_message_delete'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span><em> {!! session('flash_message_delete') !!}</em></div>
@endif
```

Here you can find different flash message stlyes [Flash Messages in Laravel 5](http://anytch.com/flash-messages-in-laravel-5/)

Answer (score 3):

I think the following would work well with lesser line of codes.

```
        session()->flash('toast', [
        'status' => 'success', 
        'body' => 'Body',
        'topic' => 'Success']
    );
```

I'm using a toaster package, but you can have something like this in your view.

```
             toastr.{{session('toast.status')}}(
              '{{session('toast.body')}}', 
              '{{session('toast.topic')}}'
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use session() global helper instead of Session

```
// flash message create
session()->flash('message', 'This is a message!'); 
session()->flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger'); 

// get flash message by key from your blade file
@if(session()->has('message'))
<p class="alert {{ session('alert-class') }}">{{ session('message') }}</p>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this might be very old thread! This is very effective way of doing it in view

`

```html
@foreach(['success', 'warning', 'info', 'message'] as $alert)
     @if (Session::has($alert))
        <div class="alert alert-{{$alert}}" role="alert">{{Session::get($alert)}}</div>
     @endif
@endforeach
```

`

Comment: This is practically the same solution as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25657068), except not prefixed with "alert-".

Comment: And there is no "alert-message" class in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Why do we need to overcomplicate a simple task?

My approach is:

```php
redirect()->route('route name')->with([
 'type' => 'error',
 'message' => ''
])
```

And in the blade template, you can access and display the session data as:

```php
@if (Session::has('message'))
    <div @class([
           'bg-red-100 text-red-500' => Session::get('type') == 'error', 
           'p-4 mb-4 text-sm text-blue-800 rounded-lg bg-blue-50'
          ]) role="alert">
       {{ Session::get('message') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

With this, you can dynamically adjust the classes for `error`, `info`, or `warning` messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Bootstrap Alert to make your view more interactive. You can do something like this:

In your function:-

```
if($author->save()){
    Session::flash('message', 'Author has been successfully added');
    Session::flash('class', 'success'); //you can replace success by [info,warning,danger]
    return redirect('main/successlogin');
```

In your views:-

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
    <div class="alert alert-{{Session::get('class')}} alert-dismissible fade show w-50 ml-auto alert-custom"
        role="alert">
        {{ Session::get('message') }}
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use global helper session like

```
session()->get('message')
```

and

```
session()->flash('message')
```

Comment: This doesn't address the problem.