# How to use flash message with html tags in laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, html-safe

I'm using flash message with laravel to display notification to users.
I want to include `html` tags in my message.
For example:
`Flash::overlay('Votre compte n’est pas encore activé.<a href="link_to_activation">activate</a>');`

Comment: And what problem are you having? Could you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question

Comment: I want to add html tags to flash message. Html tags get escaped.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be helpful to create a flash message
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#flash-data

```
Session::flash('message', 'this is a message !');
```

Comment: @KiranLM flash messages are working fine, but, if I add html tags, they will get escaped.

Comment: Sorry, HTML tags inside it may not possible, for styling, send two flash messages, one with css class name and other with text. for more reference : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004310/in-laravel-the-best-way-to-pass-different-types-of-flash-messages-in-the-sessio)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly put html in the flash message. However you can produce a very similar result utilizing bootstrap alert classes. In blade it would be something like this (your message would include your html):

```
@if (session('message')
     <div class="alert alert-info">
          <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                 {{ session('message') }}
       </div>
 @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

When outputing the message in the Blade Template file you have to do it like this

```
session('session.key.with.html')
```

That way laravel won't auto escape html tags.