# Flashed Session Data not shown in login page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I was trying to send a flash session data to my login page. Though the login page has the View of showing message but it doesn't appear:

```
$name = $request->name;
return view('cart.login',['name'=>$name])->with('success',"Login First to add to cart");
```

And this is how I was trying to display the success :

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>
              {{ $message }}
        </p>
    </div>
@endif
```

But the success message doesn't appear in the view. Can anyone help me to find out what could be possible error on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to update your code like:

Please declare *use Session* on top

```
Session::put('success', 'Login First to add to cart');

$name = $request->name;
return view('cart.login',['name'=>$name]);

@if(Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert-sucess"><p class="alert {{ Session::get('alert-class', 'alert-info') }}">{{ Session::get('success') }}</p></div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>
              {{ $message }}
        </p>
    </div>
@endif
```

To

```
@if(session()->has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('success') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

OR

```
@if (session('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a> {{ session('success') }}
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: Please see OR answer

Comment: I see the documentation because from there i got the idea of responses..BUT your OR solution also not working

Comment: if you want to use flash message then you can see this document: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21004310/in-laravel-the-best-way-to-pass-different-types-of-flash-messages-in-the-sessio

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
@if (\Session::has('success'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">
        <ul>
            <li>{!! \Session::get('success') !!}</li>
       </ul>
   </div>
@endif
```

Comment: try this code *return view('cart.login',['name'=>$name])->withSuccess("Login First to add to cart")*;