# How to add my own custom class in Laravel 5?

Tags: class, laravel

Ok, in laravel 4, if I want to add my own custom class, eg : library\myFunction.php then I do the following steps :

1. add "**myFunctions.php**" into ***app/library/myFunctiosn.php***
2. at ***app/start/global.php*** , within ***ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(*** , I add ***app_path().'/library',***
3. And to call it within my blade view, I add the following codes

```html
<?php
  $FmyFunctions1 = new myFunctions;
  $is_ok1=($FmyFunctions1->is_ok());   
?>
```

4. The contents of app/library/myFunctions.php is :

```html
<?php namespace App\library {

    class myFunctions {
        public function is_ok() {
            return 'myFunction is OK';
        }
    }

}
?>
```

And it works.

**But how to do so in Laravel 5 ???**

PS : I read [What are the best practices and best places for laravel 4 helpers or basic functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088917/what-are-the-best-practices-and-best-places-for-laravel-4-helpers-or-basic-funct/17091089#17091089)

And tried to add ***"app/library/",*** to the ***autoload array*** and run ***composer dum-autoload*** , but it keeps give me error :

> FatalErrorException in xxxx line xx: Class 'myFunctions' not found

I'm also already trying to use :

```
composer update
composer dump-autoload 
php artisan dump
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan dump-autoload
php artisan optimize
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:scan
php artisan route:list
```

But still doesn't work...

Comment: Try running composer dump-autoload instead

Comment: already and doesn't work either

Comment: use namespace autoloading in composer.json

Comment: already and doesn't work...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After some trial and error, I found the answer.

There is no need to modify Composer. Just modify the Blade into:

```html
<?php
  $FmyFunctions1 = new \App\library\myFunctions;
  $is_ok = ($FmyFunctions1->is_ok());
?>
```

Answer (score 38):

[This](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-how-to-add-custom-php-classes-in-l5) should help you.

FYI:
Basically, you could create another directory within app, and then namespace your files in there as appropriate:

app/CustomStuff/CustomDirectory/SomeClass.php.

Then, within your SomeClass.php, make sure you namespace it:

```
<?php 
namespace App\CustomStuff\CustomDirectory;

class Someclass {}
```

Now, you can access this class using the namespace within your classes:

```
use App\CustomStuff\CustomDirectory\SomeClass;
```

Comment: Filename & Class name should have the same name.

Comment: This is right, but you also need to add the folder to composer.json as specified in Amit's answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319341/class-not-found-when-using-custom-class