# Class not found when using custom class

Tags: laravel-5.3

I am using excel reader from https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader and it is in app folder.

Now when I try to access it from HomeController.php using following code.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

use App\spreadsheet_reader\php_excel_reader\excel_reader2;
use App\spreadsheet_reader\SpreadsheetReader;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
   {
        require_once(base_path().'/app/spreadsheet_reader/php_excel_reader/excel_reader2.php');

       $Reader = new \App\spreadsheet_reader\SpreadsheetReader(base_path().'/UnRegisterClient.xlsx');
   }
}
```

Then it gives me following error.

Class 'App\spreadsheet_reader\SpreadsheetReader' not found

Any suggesstion how I can solve this? I mean how I can use my custom class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `SpreadsheetReader` is not defined in the `namespace`. You should call just `new \SpreadsheetReader(...)` or add `use SpreadsheetReader` and then call it `new SpreadsheetReader()`

Answer (score 4):

Put your external files in the folder `app/Libraries` *(first, create the Libraries folder)* then just autoload the folder with that file.

For example, add this folder in the array or “classmap” in `composer.json` :

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app\Libraries"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
```

Then run `composer dump-autoload` in your command line.

Comment: Thanks for giving suggestions. Up vote for you as well

Comment: Great, but somehow this suggestion looks more in a Laravel way, instead of doing `require_once` everywhere you want to use it.

Comment: In a roundabout way this solved my problem. I had created a new directory in App and I needed to add it to the classmap.