# what is the path where i can put CustomDB.php so i can use it from a controller or a view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have made a class **CustomDB** in **CustomDB.php** file which have simillar functions of **DB** built in laravel, I can't find the path where I can put the file **CustomDB.php** so I can easily write `use CustomDB;` like  `use DB;` in either view or controller to have the ability to use this **CustomDB** class functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add my own custom class in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942390/how-to-add-my-own-custom-class-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

**DB** is a [Facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades) and you should add Facades namespace in your application (app/Facades/CustomDB.php). Next, add the following changes in **config/app.php**.

From:

```
'DB' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::class,
```

To:

```
'DB' => App\Facades\CustomDB::class,
```