# How to define global functions with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have found a few guides like this http://www.mackhankins.com/blog/defining-your-own-helper-classes-in-laravel-4 but it isnt really what im looking for as i want to be able to use functions to modify values that arent members of a class.

I have a lot of regex functions that will modify strings if they match a pattern and return a modified string. I want to be able to call these functions as if they were built in php functions.  is what i would have always done in the past, but i want to do this right.

This post [What are the best practices and best places for laravel 4 helpers or basic functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088917/what-are-the-best-practices-and-best-places-for-laravel-4-helpers-or-basic-funct) seems to be getting closer, but im still not clear on why i would have to instantiate an object just to run a basic function.

Comment: regardless of do-ability, sounds like a terrible idea going against all sorts of best practice

Comment: What about it is bad practice? There is nothing wrong with functions. In fact, Laravel 5 makes heavy use of functions. `view();` `redirect()`, etc.

Comment: instead of putting bunch of unrelated functions in the same file making global.... use facade??????

Comment: @itachi Seems overkill. I don't see `UtilClass::someRegExpMethod()` being any better then `someRegExpFunction()` or `MyNamespace\Util\someRegExpFunction()`

Answer (score 2):

Just plop all your custom functions in a file names something like "helpers.php". You don't need to do anything special.

You could either directly include the file in your bootstrap file or just set composer up to auto-load it.

Comment: From what ive read this is considered bad practice?? Is it ok to go ahead and do this anyway?

Comment: @DanHastings I don't see anything wrong with it. Not much difference between a global function and a class with a bunch of static methods. You can also namespace your functions just as like with classes if you're concerned with naming collisions.

Comment: ive always done it this way so it makes sense to me to it like this. I just second guess everything ever since i started working with laravel since everything i once knew is now wrong :P anyway this does exactly what i wanted. thanks